# Rails 3.1 - Dynamic Select Menus

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've followed and am using the Dynamic Select Menus as show in the revised Railscast (episode #88) to select Primary Genre and an associated Sub-Genre. Everything seemed to be working fine but i've now noticed that certain primary genres aren't pulling through their sub-genres. It seems that a Genre with a space in it's name is stopping things working. In the Railscast example I can't see any reference to handling this. Can anyone suggest a fix for this? I imagine it's a case of doing some kind of parsing, but not sure where to start with this.

The Railscast is here
http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised
I've followed it exactly. The only difference is I have Primary Genre/Sub-Genre like:

Rock / Punk Rock
Rock / Indie Rock
Rock / Hard Rock

Dance & Electronic / Techno
Dance & Electronic / Drum & Bass
Dance & Electronic / Electronica

Rock selects work fine, Dance & Electronic do not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you missed the step about escaping the text in the first select menu?

```
country = $('#person_country_id :selected').text()
escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
```

Check out the last section: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=asciicast